# Assign the AUTO_INCREMENT value to another field

Tags: php, codeigniter

Need your help. I have a table with 3 columns (id, name, filename) `name` and `filename` are a string. The `id` field is `AUTO_INCREMENT` so I don't have to post it on array. But the problem is on the `filename` field which is a combination string of `id` and `name` with '-' delimiter.
My expected results of `filename` is

```
+---+-------+-----------+
|id | Name  | Filename  |
+---+-------+-----------+
| 1 | James | 1-James   |
| 2 | John  | 2-John    |
| 3 | Clark | 3-Clark   |
+---+-------+-----------+
```

My code is:

```
    $data = array(  
        'name' = $this->input->post('name');
        'filename' =$this->input->id->post('name');
    )

    $this->db->insert('dbname', $data)
?>
```

Comment: You have to first do the insert (with just a name), get the insert_id ($this->db->insert_id()) back and then update the row with the filename.

Comment: You could just NOT store it in database and "build" the filename on the fly when you need it.

Comment: you can run trigger on the table, to set dynamic filename

Comment: I recommend you do not do this. You have all your data *double* now. Just create a like so: `function getFilename($user){return $user->getId().'-'.$user->getName();}`

Comment: @jonas3344 - Please check my solution. Just add trigger and it will execute automatically without doing double operations on single insert.

Comment: I'm not a fan of doing such stuff in the database because you can easily loose track of what you're doing. I like seeing such stuff in the code directly. But maybe that's just a personal thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first insert data. Then get last inserted Id and using this you need to update record

```
$data = array(  
        'name' => $this->input->post('name');
        'filename' => $this->input->id->post('name');
    )

    $this->db->insert('dbname', $data);
    $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $new_file_name = $last_id."-".$this->input->post('name');
    $update_data = array(
        'filename' => $new_file_name;
      );
    $this->db->where('id',$last_id);
    $this->db->update('dbname', $update_data);
```